# Sum of heads in a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I want a function that gives me the sum of all the heads of all lists in a given list. I am trying with this:

```
verticalParity :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int
verticalParity (x:xs) (y:ys) = x + y
```

Why I can't do this?

```
map verticalParity [[2,0,2,2,2,1], [5000,0,2,3,2,1], [26,1,2,3,44,4]]
```

Comment: to map it OP actually needs an [Int] -> a, but it looks like OP really wants to fold something

Answer (score 8):

This will do what you have described

```
sum . map head
```

The function you posted doesn't work because what you are trying to accomplish isn't a map, it's a fold (which sum is an example of).

You could also change your verticalParity function to this

```
verticalParity :: Int -> [Int] -> Int
verticalParity x (y:ys) = x + y
```

and use this

```
foldl verticalParity 0 [[2,0,2,2,2,1],[5000,0,2,3,2,1],[26,1,2,3,44,4]]
```

Comment: @user1876106 0 is the starting value. The sum of any zero things is 0.

Comment: How can I put in a list the sum applied to the head element but to the others too? For example [[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,0,0]]=[3,1,1]. Thanks

Comment: @user1876106, `map sum . transpose` (`transpose` is from `Data.List`.)

Comment: There is no other way to do it? With verticalParity done by @Dirk Holsopple? Thanks